# I encounter an error while i trying to redirect from one page to another in my demo site page

Tags: header

What this actually means?
I dont understand the error. Please help me

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mksdemo/public_html/Admin/login.php:31) in /home/mksdemo/public_html/Admin/login.php on line 84

on line no 31 only

Answer (score 0):

This means you have added some echo statement before making the redirect . You should change the location and do the exit from the script and it should be done in the beginning itself

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do your redirect using the `header()` function, however, according to HTTP protocol, all headers have to be issued before any content is sent (using something like `echo`, `print()`, or even a closing `?>` tag). It sounds like you are calling `header()` in

`login.php` on line 84

and you have something sending content in

`login.php` on line 31

You should make sure the header is being sent before this and all other possible lines of output.